# creating List<myClass>

Tags: c#, class

I'm a novices programmer, I hope I can explain this well. I typically instance a class in a loop. Sending it a file path for example and having it do it's thing and adding the created instance to a list for me to iterate through later. I have a case where I'm using batch tools to perform a number of actions on the file at the end of the file path. In this case create several new files from the existing file. Well it takes a while to process each file and the batch tools don't have any events that I can control the process with (that I know of). So the first file isn't complete and I get en error creating the second file because it's dependent on the first file. So i'm calling Thread.Sleep(500) between each, not great. But if I generate all of the first file type, then go back over and generate all of the second file type from the first ones...

A -> A -> A, B -> B -> B

instead of

A -> B, A -> B, A -> B

I won't have that issue. I can pass my class a List and have it generate all of my files without any problem, but cannot create the List. I wont end up with an object I can manipulate in other parts of the program. What am I looking for here to solve this? Like I said I'm learning programming and don't really know what my problem is. Thank you.

Comment: Figure out how to articulate your problem, then you shall receive a solution.

Comment: Can you show some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you're done creating the files I would recommend using `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles(string path)` to get `FileInfo` objects for each of the files you created. You can do this like;

```
   FileInfo[] newFiles = DirectoryInfo.GetFiles(pathToWhereICreatedTheFiles);\
```

The msdn docs for that method can be found here; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8he88b63(v=vs.110).aspx

The `FileInfo` class has the meta data necessary to do just about anything with the files. Docs on the `FileInfo` class can be found here; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes, FileInfo objects are what I started with. I envisioned sending each to my class and having it generate the additional files and set them up as properties of my object. When I had the performance issue, I wasn't sure what my options were. Creating all of the supporting files ahead of time, them associating them with my objects doesn't sound ideal either. I'm creating a viewer, each object needs to have a reference to the original file, the generated image, loads of data from the original file. Plus keep tract of whether or not it's been updated. I really didn't know. Thank you very much.